# Explicação sobre loop de redirecionamento

Tags: c#, asp.net, navegador-de-internet

vou p/ uma reunião e vão perguntar porque tem dados alguns Loop de Redirecionamento. No código, coloquei um parâmetro false e tem resolvido, mas vira e mexe ele volta. A pergunta é: O que é loop de redirecionamento? O que eu quero é apenas uma explicação, uma teoria sobre o assunto e nada mais. Não é código de como evitar, é o que é mesmo na teoria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop de redirecionamento é quando ocorre a seguinte situação:

Sejam A, B e C páginas quaiquer.

1. ao acessar A, ela redireciona para B.
2. ao acessar B, ela redireciona para C.
3. ao acessar C, ela redireciona para A.

Note que formou um looping infinito de redirecionamentos. O browser, espertinho, identifica este caso, e gera uma mensagem de erro ao invés de ficar realizando requisições até o usuário interferir no processo.

Outro erro que pode ocorrer, é o erro "Too Many Redirects", que significa que houveram muitos redirecionamentos. Alguns browsers (Chrome se não me engano) conta quandos redirects em sequência ocorrem e os interrompe no momento que a quantidade excede um valor.